# How can I find the element in this page for scraping?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, element

The website is basically a colour swatch as can be seen here:
https://prnt.sc/sux913

Once I get to this page I need to to go through all colours and for the program to provide me with the stock quantity for a size i've specified.  (Sometimes somebody wants to know the available quantity in all colours in a large.).  At this point i'm pretty lost as i can't find the element i'm meant to be referencing in my code.  If the specified size is 'L' , i need to go through each colour and provide the Qty for L. For example, Black L - 9, Navy L - 23, Red L - 334

```
              <div class="prod__options">
                <span class="attr_text">1.Pick a Color</span>
                <p id="prod_color_swatch_area_id" class ="prod_color_swatch_area">

                    <a id="prod_color_box_Black" href ="javaScript: categoryDisplayJS.displayColorSelected('BK                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            ', 'Black'); categoryDisplayJS.displayPDPErrorSection(null,null,null); setCurrentId('prod_color_box_Black'); if(submitRequest()){ cursor_wait();
                        wc.render.updateContext('ProductPageMatrixDisplay_Context',{'productId':'497940','colorSelected':'Black'});}" title ="Black">

                                  <img src="https://a248.e.akamai.net/f/248/9086/10h/origin-d5.scene7.com/is/image/Hanesbrands/HBI_498P_Black_sw?$productSwatch$" border="1" onclick="setOptions('Black', true)" />

                    </a>   



                                                <a id="prod_color_box_Smoke Gray" href ="javaScript: categoryDisplayJS.displayColorSelected('8Q', 'Smoke Gray'); categoryDisplayJS.displayPDPErrorSection(null,null,null); setCurrentId('prod_color_box_Smoke Gray'); if(submitRequest()){ cursor_wait();
                                                wc.render.updateContext('ProductPageMatrixDisplay_Context',{'productId':'497940','colorSelected':'Smoke Gray'});}" title ="Smoke Gray">

                                                            <img src="https://a248.e.akamai.net/f/248/9086/10h/origin-d5.scene7.com/is/image/Hanesbrands/HBI_498P_SmokeGray_sw?$productSwatch$" border="1" onclick="setOptions('SmokeGray', true)" />

                                                </a>



                                                <a id="prod_color_box_Charcoal Heather" href ="javaScript: categoryDisplayJS.displayColorSelected('HL', 'Charcoal Heather'); categoryDisplayJS.displayPDPErrorSection(null,null,null); setCurrentId('prod_color_box_Charcoal Heather'); if(submitRequest()){ cursor_wait();
                                                wc.render.updateContext('ProductPageMatrixDisplay_Context',{'productId':'497940','colorSelected':'Charcoal Heather'});}" title ="Charcoal Heather">

                                                            <img src="https://a248.e.akamai.net/f/248/9086/10h/origin-d5.scene7.com/is/image/Hanesbrands/HBI_498P_CharcoalHeather_sw?$productSwatch$" border="1" onclick="setOptions('CharcoalHeather', true)" />

                                                </a>



                                                <a id="prod_color_box_Navy" href ="javaScript: categoryDisplayJS.displayColorSelected('NY', 'Navy'); categoryDisplayJS.displayPDPErrorSection(null,null,null); setCurrentId('prod_color_box_Navy'); if(submitRequest()){ cursor_wait();
                                                wc.render.updateContext('ProductPageMatrixDisplay_Context',{'productId':'497940','colorSelected':'Navy'});}" title ="Navy">

                                                            <img src="https://a248.e.akamai.net/f/248/9086/10h/origin-d5.scene7.com/is/image/Hanesbrands/HBI_498P_Navy_sw?$productSwatch$" border="1" onclick="setOptions('Navy', true)" />
```

The last code i tried was as below:

```
html_content = requests.get(browser.current_url)
print(browser.current_url) # just to check what the URL is
print(html_content.raise_for_status())
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html_content.text, 'html.parser')
ele_color_swatch = soup.select('#prod_color_swatch_area_id')
print(ele_color_swatch)
```

However, that just gave:

```
https://www... (some long url)
None
[]
```

Comment: The data is probably loaded dynamically via JavaScript. Can you share URL?

Comment: I can do but there is a login first so i don't think you'll be able to view anything.